# ASP.NET Response Redirect of URL Error; from static method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I am working on ASP.NET 3.5 App. I have $ajax jQuery function calling code-behind method with sending staff ID.

I want Response.Redirect to open from this method but getting following error

[image]

### $ajax function calling code-behind method

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'AddUserInRole.aspx/GetRolesListFilteredByStaff_NotIn',
       type: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify({ GivenStaffID: selectStaffIDToAddRole }),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
               alert(response.d);
        },
       failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                   }
       }).done(function (response) {
                   //
  });
```

### Code-Behind Method

```
[WebMethod]
private static void GetRolesListFilteredByStaff_NotIn(string GivenStaffID)
 {
    Response.Redirect("/SelectRoleForStaff.aspx?staffID='GivenStaffID'");            
 }
```

my 2nd question is how to read staffID from url in new upload page

### Update Partial Answer

I have managed to call the require method but its not redirecting page...

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static void GetRolesListFilteredByStaff_NotIn(string GivenStaffID)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/SelectRoleForStaff.aspx?staffID="+GivenStaffID);            
    }
```

Comment: Is this an .asmx fille where the exception occurs?

Comment: have a look in my question under Update Partial Answer ....

Comment: many thanks...........

Comment: ok let me rephrase that. Is the file you've got that method a aspx or asmx file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90528/discussion-between-oluwafemi-and-toxic).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update your method to return the url to redirect like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetRolesListFilteredByStaff_NotIn(string GivenStaffID)
{
   return "SelectRoleForStaff.aspx?staffID=" + GivenStaffID;
}
```

And in your ajax success do this:

```
success: function (response) {
               window.location = response;
               // OR
               window.location = response.d;
        },
```

Comment: In my case the page is having a postback and javascript function is not able to run